# Allowing the user to change application state (f.ex. language) in a RESTful web-app

Tags: rest

I am currently re-writing an old web-application and I want it to be RESTful. Now, one *important* philosophy behind a RESTful app, is that each request to the end-point has to be **stateless**.

With the application I am aiming for a common codebase for the API as for normal browsing. In other words, I want to *avoid* special URLs like `http://api.domain.tld` or `http://domain.tld/api`. I intend to interpret the HTTP `Accept` header for this.

One challenge I came up with, are request parameters, that a user browsing the page usually only chooses once. A good example for this is the language. Again, I can use the `Accept-Language` header to pick an *initial* language. But what if the user wishes to change this? It would be unusable if the user needed to switch the language after each request.

In my opinion, this is really a request parameter, and should be passed on as such. For example: `http://domain.tld/resource?lang=en`. So once the user switched the language, I would need to append this parameter to *each* URL on the page.

In a way, this makes the browsing-session stateful. Are there any "best practices" for this? How would *you* approach this. One idea I have, is to store these "global" parameters in the session, but add them to each URL nevertheless. If only to make the API easily discoverable.

**On a sidenote:** I am currently building the web-page using [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) which provides a method `url_for` to build URLs. I am considering overriding this, so each generated URL will have the parameter. But this is not a Flask specific problem. This is something most RESTful services should consider, so I will tag it neither with python, nor flask!

Answer (score 1):

#### State Transfer

REST doesn't require each request to be stateless. The requirement is that the **server does not have to manage state on behalf of the client**. In effect, each **request has to carry sufficient state** to allow the server to process it.

Your approach, providing the user language is perfectly sensible. Others might prefer to retrieve it from a shared database but this can have some scalability concerns.

Comment: After giving your response a bit more thought, I am inclined to say that the requests should indeed be stateless. Saying that "each request has to carry sufficient state to allow the server to process it", means very much stateless to me. I *do* believe however, that this it is debatable how far one ins willing to go. In my case, I want to offer a public API. And I would like to make it easy to request a resource with as little requests as possible. So having the requests as stateless as possible is beneficial.